# SSH/SFTP over WiFi issues

Tags: ssh, cisco, wifi

Some time ago we have purchased a Wireless Controller (AIR-CT2504-K9) with few Access Points (MIMO 3x3). The number of users on one access point is around 20-25 simultaneously. As I have understood correctly, this is around 8 users per one channel. Besides we have a second access point in 5m range, behind a little wall.

We have 3 Mac users who complain about the speed of the SSH/SFTP connections.
When one of them tries to download something from our hosting machine (outside our network), the rest can't use SSH connection to any other server. At the same time the download speed is going down from 1Mbps to 0... then it drops.

I have tried to reproduce the issue with Windows machine. The situation is a bit better, at least no dramatic speed drop. But from time to time download stops, SSH connection on both Mac and my Windows machine hangs. After few seconds it is working again. So Windows machine doesn't kill the other machines completely, as Mac does.

In order to exclude Router config and remote host config we have tried to work over cable. No single issue occurred.

I have also established loggin, but have not found anything related to these drops. Even the number of events has not increased.

What could be a problem? Too many people?
Are there any possibility to set priority for SSH protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I found a solution. Not sure which one of the following worked, but now my WiFi users can download via SSH with about 2Mbps speed. And of course no connection drops.

1. First, I have made prioritization for SSH ports in both directions.
2. Second, I have enabled Load Balancing and Band Selection. Fortunately till now it is impacting our Skype calls.